# How to create a drag and drop canvas in React

Tags: reactjs, jointjs

I need to implement a function were i could drag and drop some svg icons and create a garden like map in react. what are the best libraries to achieve this?? i found a library called `JointJS`. Any examples on how to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best library for Drag n drop in react for me is that one from abramov (redux's creator):

https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/